# How to handle empty argument value in python function of Django views?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have an application that passes the user name from the HTML template to the URL and functions in the views. 
views.py

```
def cv_detail_view(request, username):
    if username=='':
        return redirect("accounts:login")
    else:
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        try:
            personal_info = PersonalInfo.objects.get(user=user)
        except PersonalInfo.DoesNotExist:
            # if personal info doesn't exist redirect to create or 404 page.
            if user == request.user:
                return redirect("cvs:create_personal_info")
            else:
                raise Http404("CV Does Not Exist.")

        work_experience = WorkExperience.objects.filter(user=user)
        education = Education.objects.filter(user=user)

        context = {
                    "personal_info": personal_info,
                    "work_experience": work_experience,
                    "education": education,
                  }

        return render(request, "detail.html", context)
```

Html snippet:

```
<li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cvs:cv_detail' username=request.user.username %}">Use templates</a></li>
```

ursl.py

```
path(r'^(?P<username>[\w._-]+)/$',views.cv_detail_view,name='cv_detail'),
```

My idea is to redirect users to login page if the parameter `username` is empty i.e, if the user is not logged in. However, I get the following error:

```
    NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'cv_detail' with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cvs/\\^\\(\\?P(?P<username>[^/]+)\\[\\\\w\\._\\-\\]\\+\\)/\\$\\Z']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:9090/
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'cv_detail' with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cvs/\\^\\(\\?P(?P<username>[^/]+)\\[\\\\w\\._\\-\\]\\+\\)/\\$\\Z']
```

Is there any way to handle the empty value in function arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add in the template this:

```
{% if request.user.username %}
  <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cvs:cv_detail' username=request.user.username %}">Use templates</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It worked! That was a silly miss from my end. Thanks for identifying it.

Comment: If the username is not found i.e, if the username value is empty then is there any way to still make the function redirect to login page?

Comment: Maybe you have to manage this check in the view that render the html above:  
`if not username: return redirect("accounts:login")`

Comment: I have added ```if username=='':```, doesn't that make sense?

Comment: Check if username field can be None (Null value in DB), so your check does not work.

Comment: Argh! Yes, it cannot be null. However, I found an alternative to handle the redirect in frontend itself. Thanks for the idea